# Excel Connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

Excel Connections Questions.
I have created workbook that will be sent to my employees that is connected to an SQL server that runs a query after the data is refreshed.  The question I have is I don’t want to give the employees the password to the SQL server so I created a new worksheet called password and hid the password the password in cell a1.  After I hid the worksheet and enabled password protection.
In order to grab the password I attempted to create a connection using this code:

```
DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=DOH001UA1101SW2;UID=RawPackagesDataLogin;PWD=password!A1;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;WSID=DOH001UA2051HD9;DATABASE=PackagesRawData
```

But kept getting an error that it wasn’t able to connect.  Can anyone help with my code?

Comment: From a security point of view would it not be better to write a small app that grabbed the data from the excel workbook and then posted the data to your database? That way you could run any checks you wanted on the data before updating your database. Also, it would resolve your password problem as you would be able to connect through the app and they needn't know the password. Not really answering your question I know, but might be a better course of action.

Comment: What difference does it make if they can see the password or not if you are giving them access to the data anyways? They could just as simply modify the query to get any info, or damage any info they want.

Comment: You can also set the connection string inside VBA and password protect your VBA.

Comment: SR28- Its above my pay grade. They didnt like teh app idea.

Comment: We just don't want them to change things on the server.

Comment: Can you post the actual snippet of VBA code that you are using to construct the connection string? I suspect it's not retrieving the value from the cell properly.

Comment: `We just don't want them to change things on the server.` You are giving them connection to the database, they can do whatever they want with it, they don't have to know the password.

Comment: @user2140261 - That's the point of the app. You would remove all connection to the database within the excel spreadsheet. The spreadsheet would simply hold the data they wish refreshed / changed etc. The app extracts the data, runs some data checks, connects to the database and makes the various updates. Removes the possibility of the user damaging the database.

Comment: It's VERY easy to break into a hidden or protected worksheet's data. Don't use that approach. Rather use you users's credentials on the network (UserID). Implement a table in on your DB that returns data to the user based on who they are, a very basic security table. Additionally your DRIVER doesn't look right. Look at this link : http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/